# Azure CLI command to create ADF linked service with key vault?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, key-value, azure-cli

[image]I am referencing the below codes with command but getting error for both

az datafactory linked-service create --resource-group $resourcegroup --factory-name $factoryname --linked-service-name ls_AzureKeyVault_storage --properties @ls_AzureKeyVault_storage.json > \dev\null

{
"name": "ls_AzureKeyVault_storage",
"properties": {
"annotations": [],
"type": "AzureKeyVault",
"typeProperties": {
"baseUrl": "https://kvadfconnections.vault.azure.net/"
}
}
}

az datafactory linked-service create --resource-group $resourcegroup --factory-name $factoryname --linked-service-name AzureStorageLinkedService --properties @AzureStorageLinkedService.json > \dev\null

{
"name": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
"properties": {
"annotations": [],
"type": "AzureBlobStorage",
"typeProperties": {
"connectionString": {
"type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
"store": {
"referenceName": "ls_AzureKeyVault_storage",
"type": "LinkedServiceReference"
},
"secretName": "sec-stforadfcli-connection"
}
}
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices"
}

Answer (score 0):

We have tested this in our local environment, Below statements are based on our analysis.

While creating the linked service through  `AzureCLI` cmdlet using `az data factory linked-service create` ,you need to pass the json file to the `--properties flag`  .

```
az datafactory linked-service create --factory-name
                                     --linked-service-name
                                     --properties
                                     --resource-group
                                     [--if-match]
```

- If you declare the `properties{}` list on top of the `typeproperties{}` in your json file then while creating the linked service to the data factory it will fail with the error that you have shared as shown in the below

[image]

- You Need pass only `typeProperties` in json file to create a linked service with the data factory  as shown in the below.

In the below example ,we are trying to create a `keyvault` linked service with our existing ADF.
Here is our `keyvault.json` file which has type properties.

```
{
    "type": "AzureKeyVault",
    "typeProperties":{
        "baseUrl": "<keyvault>"
    },
    "annotations":[<requiredannotations],
    "description":"<requireddescription>",
    "parameters": {
        "test":{
            "type":"String",
            "defaultValue":"test"
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the sample output for reference :**

[image]

You can use the above `keyvault.json` file as reference & make the changes as per your requirement.

You can also refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/linked-services/create-or-update#azurekeyvaultlinkedservice) documentation, for more information about what all the  properties that we can pass to `AzurekeyVaultLinkedService` & there respective datatypes.